# What is Post = form => {} in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, form-submit

I have a form with submit button. following code is  js code for this form:
**(note: I Know javascript Anonimous function but it is little bit diffrent types of form submit)** Please explain how this Anonimous fucntion work

```
Post = form => {
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: form.action,
                    data: new FormData(form),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (res) {}
});
```

here, what is `post = form =>` mean? what this kind of code is called in javascript?(  Is it method or event call or anything else?)

I think this is anonymous functions in JS. but how does event is fire when I click on submit button.

Comment: "how does event is fire when I click on submit button" — Taking that literally: That's what submit buttons *do* (trigger submit events). If you mean "How does this function get called in response to a submit event?" then (all else being equal): It doesn't. The code to register it as an event listener isn't included in your question.

Comment: Given there's no `let Post =` (or `var Post =`) this looks like it's part of a larger component/library/object - so how it's triggered on submit will be based on how the component listens for submit, then calls its own code with `Post` being an option in that component.